# Get Windows Current LoggedIn User in C# Daemon Service

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core

I have a daemon service in.NetCore 3.1. It is executed by Windows TaskScheduler. It needs to capture the window's current logged-in username. How to do it? Tried few options-

1. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.
2. Environment.UserName.

Both above are not giving logged-in username. When I execute the daemon service manually, then only they give the correct username.

WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name -> It is always returning SYSTEM as username when daemon service is executed by TaskScheduler.

Environment.UserName -> It is always returning Windows Hostname as username when daemon service is executed by TaskScheduler.

Kindly suggest!

Comment: Define "Current", given that windows has long supported *multiple* login sessions, remote desktop, etc. Almost always the right answer is to have a separate program run as startup program for users when they login, and then use some form of IPC to communicate with the service.

Comment: Hi Damien. thanks for the reply. We want to run the program as a Task by TaskScheduler whenever the task is configured to run. How to get the current session for this?

Answer (score 1):

As Damien mentioned in comments, the current user can be interpreted differently.
No one needs to be logged in either.

You can try this way:

1. Retrieves the session identifier of the console session

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]

   static extern uint [WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-wtsgetactiveconsolesessionid)();

// obtain the currently active session id; every logged on user in the system has a unique session id

```
    uint dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
```

2. How to retrieve username from session ID, see:

https://smbadiwe.github.io/post/track-activities-windows-service/

Comment: Thanks @Viliam. How to implement method WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()? I am new to c# and windows. Kindly help!

Comment: It is API function, you can use DLL import, this way:

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

Answer (score 0):

When you create a task, you can select which user account to run the application under.  Just select a 'user' account rather than 'system', and either of the suggested methods will work.

[image]

Comment: Task in TaskScheduler is getting created programatically. Would need username again to create a task :)

Comment: Isn't the task being created at installation time?  Your installer would know who the current user is, and therefore will be able to set it to them.

Comment: We want to capture the logged-in user at the time of invocation of the task rather than who created the task.